# Simple 1 line For Loops

Tags: python

Typically I have used list comprehensions to iterate and filter by data (i.e dicts etc) within the need to write multiple line for loops.

```
[x['a']["b"] for x in s["items"] if x["car"] == "ford"]
```

However this returns a list such as :

```
[False]
```

Not a massive problem as I can write

```
[x['a']["b"] for x in s["items"] if x["car"] == "ford"][0]
```

However is there a way either with list comprehensions or another way to write a for loop which an if condition so that I only get a string returned ?

Edit : In other words how can I place the following onto a single line and return a string,

```
for x in s["items"]:
    if x["car"] == "ford":
       print x['a']['b']
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify what result you want. Your description is lacking

Comment: can you show the dict `s`?

Comment: Without glimpse of data it is hard to tell why

Comment: We need a `dict` that we can work with.

Comment: Your for loop and your comprehension are exactly the same; show your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to short-circuit at the first match.  Use `next` along with a generator expression:

```
>>> s = {'items': [{'a': {'b': 'potato'}, 'car': 'ford'}, {'a': {'b': 'spam'}, 'car': 'honda'}]}
>>> next(x['a']['b'] for x in s['items'] if x['car'] == "ford")
'potato'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have not shown that dict `s`, i have tested it with the possible data and it works fine:

```
>>> s = {'items': [{'a': {'b': 1}, 'car': 'ford'}, {'a': {'b': 1}, 'car': 'honda'}]}
>>> print [x['a']['b'] for x in s['items'] if x['car'] == "ford"]
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the *syntax* of your problem that guarantees that there is only value in `s` that satisfies the criterion. (I.E., for an arbitrary `dict` `s`, there could be more than one.)

You may be able to guarantee that to be the case, but that is external to (this part of) the code.

Hence python isn't going to be able to automatically enforce that.